how to use inotify to monitor a creation of a file and running it in the background
a beginner here.
I am trying to write a script so that when a file (called "file1" for example) is created in a directory, I can see a notification and the inotifywait command I am using is stopped.
so far, after I saw several examples this is the code I have:
#!/bin/bash     
DIRECTORY="$PWD"
    inotifywait -m -e create --format '%f' "$DIRECTORY" |
    while read FILENAME; do
      echo "File created: $FILENAME"
      if [ -f file1 ]; then
       exit
      fi
    done

But the code doesn't exit the script after file1 is created. The inotify command continue to run until I press ctrl+C.
What do I need to do in order for the code to exit on time?
also, is there a way to run it in the background while I continue with other work on the same terminal? Because it seems like the command is running on the terminal and if I want to use the command line I have to terminate the script.

Related questions: In bash, read after a pipe is not setting values, Why is my variable local in one 'while read' loop, but not in another seemingly similar loop?; also see Bash manual, Lists for asynchronous lists introduced by &.

Also, see Bash manual, Job Control.

Remove the -m option.   The default is to exit after the first occurance,  but the -m (monitor) causes it to run until canceled.
-m, --monitor
Instead of exiting after receiving a single event, execute indefinitely. The default behaviour is to exit after the first event occurs.
